# How long does it take to get n coupons with exactly k coupons being drawn at least twice?

Tags: combinatorics, coupon-collector

In the coupon collector problem, I open a cereal box every morning and get a random coupon from a set of $n$ different coupons randomly.

It is known that on average, it will take me $n H_n$ days to get all coupons (at least once).

My question is whether it is known how long it will take me to get $n$ coupons conditional on exactly $k$ coupons being drawn more than one time?

Comment: Do you want to know the expected value or do you want to know the entire distribution?

Comment: Just the expected value as a function of n and k.